# How to add environment variable to my flutter custom package properly?

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages, .env, flutter-pubspec, flutter-dotenv

I have an App and a custom package, when i try to use my package's environment variable it can not be found.
this is my package pubspec:

```
assets: 
 - 2.env
```

and this is for my App:

```
assets: 
 - 1.env
```

this is my package:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await dotenv.load(fileName: '2.env');
  print(dotenv.env['ENV_TYPE']!);
}
```

and this is how I use my package in my app:

```
import 'package:my_package/package.dart' as pack;
...
      CupertinoButton(
              child: const Text("Run Package"),
              onPressed: () {
                pack.main();
              },
            ),
```

When I use `1.env`(main App pubspec file) the package works fine(even though I have not added it in my package pubspec) and prints the value, however, when i try the `2.env` which is the file added in package pubspec I get `(FileNotFoundError)`.
First I believed that it has something to do with the path in the package pubspec so i also tryed something like this
`- packages/my_package/2.env` 
but i belive this is not the issue as the package gets up and running without a problem so I think `await dotenv.load(fileName: '2.env');` causes the problem. Why my custom package can't find it's own dependency (2.env) whereas it is fine with the app file(1.env) which is not even included in the package pubspec.

Answer (score 2):

To manage env, I use [flutter_config](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_config)

```
import 'package:flutter_config/flutter_config.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); // Required by FlutterConfig
  await FlutterConfig.loadEnvVariables();

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

in android/app/build.gradle (assuming you have flavor "staging" and "production")

```
project.ext.envConfigFiles = [staging: "env/.1.env",
    production: "env/.2.env"]


apply from: project(':flutter_config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"
```

when build, it will take 1.env or 2.env depends on the flavor.

then, you can use in your code

```
import 'package:flutter_config/flutter_config.dart';

FlutterConfig.get('ENV_TYPE')
```

on iOS, for each Scheme

[image]

It will create a .envfile at build (in iOS folder) and will replace the content with 1.env or 2.env